# How Can I Parse Json In Json With SwiftyJSON?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am returning the following JSON from an API. In my database, I store a list in JSON already. Thus, it gives us a string of JSON inside JSON. How can I access these as objects in Swift? More to the point: How can I parse JSON inside of JSON?

```js
{
  "checklists": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "account_id": 15,
      "user_id": 15,
      "object_id": 21,
      "checklist": "[{\"title\":\"Test\",\"summary\":\"Test 12\"},{\"title\":\"Test 2 \",\"summary\":\"Test 123\"}]",
      "title": "High Altitude Operations",
      "type": "other",
      "LastHistory": null,
      "CleanArray": [
        {
          "title": "Test",
          "summary": "Test 12"
        },
        {
          "title": "Test 2 ",
          "summary": "Test 123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, decode the main object.

Let's say `data` is the JSON in your question:

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
```

To get the content of the `checklist` key inside the array inside the `checklists` key, we can use SwiftyJSON's key path subscripting like this:

```
let checkList = json["checklists",0,"checklist"]
print(checkList)
```

Prints:

> [{"title":"Test","summary":"Test 12"},{"title":"Test 2 ","summary":"Test 123"}]

This is your inner JSON as a String.

Make it data, then do the same process and access the array content:

```
if let json2String = checkList.string, 
        data2 = json2String.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let json2 = JSON(data: data2)
    let checkList2 = json2[0]
    let title = checkList2["title"]
    print(title)
}
```

Prints:

> Test

Note that I've used key path subscripting for this example, but usual techniques like simple subscripting, loops and map/flatMap/etc also work:

```
let mainChecklists = json["checklists"]
for (_, content) in mainChecklists {
    if let innerString = content["checklist"].string,
            data2 = innerString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let json2 = JSON(data: data2)
        for (_, innerChecklist) in json2 {
            let title = innerChecklist["title"]
            print(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

> Test
>   Test 2

Comment: This answer made me so happy I laughed like a child after drinking an entire pitcher of Kool-Aid on a hot summers day. Thank you for the thorough and well thought out explanation.