# Cannot determine type of json object returned from web service

Tags: asp.net, json, swift, nsdictionary

I have an old type of web service built on ASP.Net. With the following function, I was able to fetch some type of data from the asmx web service:

```
func getJsonData(sql: String, spparamnames: String, spParamValues: String, completeonClosure: @escaping (AnyObject?) -> ()) {

    let url  = URL(string:"http://www.example.com/MyWebService.asmx/GetDataTableAsJson")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")        // the expected response is also JSON
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let dictionary = ["sql" : sql, "spparamnames" : spparamnames, "spparamvalues" : spParamValues] //Parameters are here seperated with comma
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error.debugDescription)                                 // some fundamental network error
            return
        }

        do {

            if response != nil {

                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
                let isCorectJson = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(myJson)
                let charcount = (myJson["d"] as? String)?.characters.count
                let cc = charcount ?? 0
                if isCorectJson == true && cc > 0 {

                    completeonClosure(myJson as AnyObject?)
                    )
                } else {
                    let str2 = "Connection Error"
                    completeonClosure(str2 as AnyObject?)
                }

            }

        } catch let JsonError {
            print(JsonError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

When I run a query with Swift, and cast the object type as `NSDictionary`, my output result is the following:

```
getJsonData(sql: "SELECT TOP 3 User_id, LoweredUserName FROM Users", spparamnames: "", spParamValues: "") {
    returnJSON in
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        let mystr = returnJSON as? NSDictionary
        print(mystr!)         
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    d = "[{\"User_id\":102,\"LoweredUserName\":\"abu alay\"},{\"User_id\":90,\"LoweredUserName\":\"ali es\"},{\"User_id\":95,\"LoweredUserName\":\"alper ay\"}]";
}
```

I think that the result is some kind of dictionary, I was not able to convert the result to an array, therefore I cannot iterate between the rows and use the result efficiently. What should I do in order to read the result like: print(returnJSON[0]["LoweredUserName"]) ? What is the meaning of the letter "d" at the beginning of the result? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The value for the "d" key in this dictionary is a String representation of another JSON object, an array of dictionaries. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37423950/2227743

Comment: Thanks Eric. Got it. The letter "d" is really an array of dictionaries. Therefore I had to add the following to my web service function to return a meaningful result: let str = myJson["d"] as? String
completeonClosure(str as AnyObject?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your response is an Array, try to cast to an array of dictionary objects.

```
if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
   // parse each object here
}
```

This example code I ran in a playground seems to work fine:

```
let jsonString = "[{\"User_id\":102,\"LoweredUserName\":\"abu alay\"},{\"User_id\":90,\"LoweredUserName\":\"ali es\"},{\"User_id\":95,\"LoweredUserName\":\"alper ay\"}]"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    print(json)
}
```

Output:

```
Optional([["User_id": 102, "LoweredUserName": abu alay], ["User_id": 90, "LoweredUserName": ali es], ["User_id": 95, "LoweredUserName": alper ay]])
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks buddy!

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer if it solved it for you. good luck with the project

Answer (score 0):

If the text you have shown is the entire body of the result you got:

```
{
  d = "[{\"User_id\":102,\"LoweredUserName\":\"abu alay\"},{\"User_id\":90,\"LoweredUserName\":\"ali es\"},{\"User_id\":95,\"LoweredUserName\":\"alper ay\"}]";
}
```

Then this is not properly formatted JSON.  For it to be formatted properly the "d" would have to be shown in double quotes.

It looks like you may need to do some custom parsing on the result to get at the JSON contained in the "d" area.